# Accessing Microsoft Dynamics from UWP app

Tags: uwp, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create a UWP app to do some stuff with Microsoft Dynamics 365.

The libraries I need are part of this nuget package: `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies`

If I try to install the latest version, I get the error:

```
NU1202  Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.12 is not compatible 
with uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299). 
Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.12 supports: net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2)
```

I'm able to successfully install an older version of the nuget package (9.0.2.5), and it all compiles.

But when I try to create a  `new OrganizationWebProxyClient(uri, false);`

I get this error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Void System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint)'.
  Source=Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.WebServiceClient.WebProxyClient`1..ctor(Uri serviceUrl, Boolean useStrongTypes)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.WebServiceClient.OrganizationWebProxyClient..ctor(Uri serviceUrl, Boolean useStrongTypes)
   at MyProject.Myclass.GetDynamicsSvc()
```

Which from my googling seems to be an indication of some library version mismatch, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Edit:

Here is the function that tries to create a new OrganizationWebProxyClient

```
public static OrganizationWebProxyClient GetDynamicsSvc()
{
    var uriString = $"http://{AppResources.CrmUrl}/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web%20SdkClientVersion=9.0";
    var uri = new Uri(uriString);

    var svc = new OrganizationWebProxyClient(uri, false);
    svc.HeaderToken = GetCRMToken();
    svc.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(9, 9, 9);
    return svc;
}
```

I just tried playing around with the uri a bit, by setting `ClientVersion=9.0.2.5`, but I get the same error.

Comment: You might want to post your code. How are you Authenticating to Dynamics? Are you using a connection string?

Comment: I added some code to the post. At this point the only thing that could be incorrect here would be my uri, but in that case wouldn't I just get a connection error?

Comment: Hi, Ash. This Nuget package is not intended for UWP applications, so some of the methods involved in this SDK are not available in UWP, so an error will be reported. If you want to use Dynamic365's services in UWP, please use WebApi to make calls.